# How to sort the name- comparator issue? please read description fully

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have a object

**Class Employee(id, name, city){ };**

```
List<Employee> list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.add(new Employee(2, "Abc", "eJ"));
list1.add(new Employee(3, "Zec", "eJ");
list1.add(new Employee(4, "Cec", "eJ"));
list1.add(new Employee(5, "Abc", "Ab"));
list1.add(new Employee(6, "Abc", "Ze"));
```

i need to sort Employee object based on **name** even along with **city**

```
"Abc","Ab" 
"Abc","eJ"
"Abc","Ze"
"Cec","eJ"
"Zec", "eJ"
```

but i am getting sorting like - ***city not getting ordered along with name.***

```
"Abc","eJ" - city not ordered here
"Abc","Ab"
"Abc","Ze"
"Cec","eJ"
"Zec", "eJ"
```

Anyone knows, plz help me wat is the issue  with comparator?

Comment: show your code how you are sorting

Comment: You'd need to compare the second attribute with `compareToIgnoreCase`

Comment: Alexis - compareToIgnoreCase is for capital and Small letters. but am asking different issue